# signalr js client onReconnecting() not fired

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I am getting trouble handling connectivity lifetime events on my signalR js client. I am using the [aspnet/signalr-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aspnet/signalr-client) npm library on the client and the microsoft.aspnetcore.signalr library on the asp.net core server.

### The problem is

when I close the server (alt+F4) the client method `onClosed(error)` gets fired, what I want is, how it is described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events), that the `onReconnecting()` method gets fired and the client tries to reconnect. I have already tried to ignore this problem and establish a new connection in the `onClosed(error)` method, but then i get a `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot start a connection that is not in the 'Initial' state.` Error.

### My Question is

Why does the `onClosed(error)` method get fired and the client doesn't try to reconnect and how could I probably fix this?

### Code for clarification:

#### Client

```
var connection = new signalR.HubConnection('http://localhost:8956/testhub');
connection.on('onStart', function() {
    console.log('onStart');
  });

  connection.on('onEnd', function() {
    console.log('onEnd');
  })

  console.log('connection=', connection);

  connection.onClosed = function(error) {   // this gets fired
    console.log('connection closed');
    //setTimeout(function() {
    //  connection.start();
    //}, 10000);
  }

  connection.onReconnecting = function() {   // this not
    console.log('trying to reconnect');
  }

  connection.start();
```

#### Server Hub 'TestHub'

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace SignalRCoreConsole.Hubs
{
    class TestHub : Hub
    {
        public void Start()
        {
            Clients.All.InvokeAsync("onStart");
            Console.WriteLine("TestHub: Start");
        }

        public void End()
        {
            Clients.All.InvokeAsync("onEnd");
            Console.WriteLine("TestHub: End");
        }

        public override Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("client disconnected");
            return base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
        }

        public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("client connected");
            return base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SignalR for Asp.NET Core does not have reconnects. You looked up the `onReconnecting` in the documentation for the previous version of SignalR but the feature is no longer there in the new version. Take a look at the [announcement](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/09/14/announcing-signalr-for-asp-net-core-2-0/) that describes bigger breaking changes between the two.

Comment: Thank you. Are there any best practices for handling disconnects?

Comment: The simplest thing is pretty much what you have. This won't take care of missing messages though...

Comment: "does not have reconnects" ?? why not, what about .withAutomaticReconnect() in the HubConnectionBuilder().

Comment: At that time reconnects were not supported. Also, my understanding is that even now the reconnect will not allow to identify and recover messages lost when the client was reconnecting.